# Подскажите знак препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Это не кто иной, как Юра Паратино() невысокий, крепкий, просоленный и просмоленный грек.

Answer (score 2):

Однородные приложения в конце предложения обособляются с помощью тире:

Это не кто иной, как Юра Паратино — невысокий, крепкий, просоленный и просмоленный грек.

Answer (score 0):

Тире вместо запятой при обособлении приложений ста­вится, если приложение находится в конце предложения и **при этом подчеркивается его самостоятельность или дается разъяснение.**

Пример:

На платане, раскинув острые крылья, сидит коршун — большая птица с горбатым клювом (В. Солоухин);

(См. http://www.yaklass.ru/p/russky-yazik/11-klass/prostoe-oslozhnennoe-predlozhenie-10915/obosoblennye-i-neobosoblennye-chleny-predlozheniia-10940/re-7007f952-43dd-43a5-9275-44e19ddf55de)

У Куприна так: **Юра Паратино вот каков: это невысокий, крепкий, просоленный и просмоленный грек, лет сорока**

А у составителей задания — переиначивателей Куприна — над спросить, знаком ли читатель с Юрой. Если знаком, то запятая, если нет, то возможны варианты. Если в духе Куприна (Это не кто иной, как Юра Паратино, и вот он каков), то тире. Если в том смысле, что вот, мол, невысокий, крепкий, просоленный и просмоленный грек Юра Паратино, то запятая.